# The keybindings I set for NERDTree and Telescope does not work after LSP started to work using Neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

I have a problem with my configuration in NeoVim. After I managed to get LSP (with lspconfig) to work I noticed the keys I implemented for NERDTree and other extension (Telescope) did not work. However when I execute the functions from Nerdtree then it works. So the problema may come to some misconfiguration of keybindings.

The configuration I set for lspconfig is:

```
lua << EOF
local nvim_lsp = require('lspconfig')

-- Use an on_attach function to only map the following keys
-- after the language server attaches to the current buffer
local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  local function buf_set_keymap(...) vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, ...) end
  local function buf_set_option(...) vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, ...) end

  -- Enable completion triggered by <c-x><c-o>
  buf_set_option('omnifunc', 'v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc')

  -- Mappings.
  local opts = { noremap=true, silent=true }

  -- See `:help vim.lsp.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
  buf_set_keymap('n', 'gD', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', 'gd', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', 'K', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', 'gi', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '<C-k>', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '<leader>wa', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '<leader>wr', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '<leader>wl', '<cmd>lua print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '<leader>D', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.type_definition()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '<leader>rn', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.rename()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '<leader>ca', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', 'gr', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.references()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '<leader>e', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.show_line_diagnostics()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '[d', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.goto_prev()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', ']d', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.goto_next()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '<leader>q', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.set_loclist()<CR>', opts)
  buf_set_keymap('n', '<leader>F', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting()<CR>', opts)
end

-- Use a loop to conveniently call 'setup' on multiple servers and
-- map buffer local keybindings when the language server attaches
local servers = { 'pyright', 'rust_analyzer', 'tsserver', 'eslint' }
for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  nvim_lsp[lsp].setup {
    on_attach = on_attach,
    flags = {
      debounce_text_changes = 150,
    }
  }
 end
 EOF
```

The keybindings I set for NerdTree is:

```
map <leader>t :call NERDTreeToggle()<CR>
```

After tweaking some configuration I didn't come up with an idea of what is possibly going on. Any help would be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your keybindings? I would try the following:

`:map`

When you remove the **lspconfig** does *NERDTree* it still work?